# PHP Add Signature to POST Request

Tags: php, hash

I am trying to make a POST request with PHP. I am trying to submit a users name along with a generated hash. The following is the code I currently have:

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST["name"]) && crypt($_POST["name"],'saltgoeshere') == $_POST["hash"] )
    {
        echo "Name is ". $_POST['name']. "<br />";
        exit();
    }
    else if( isset($_POST["name"]) && crypt($_POST["name"],'saltgoeshere') != $_POST["hash"] ) {echo "Invalid/Tampered Request?"; exit();}
?>
<html>
<body>
  <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
  Password: <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo crypt($name,"saltgoeshere");?>" />
  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The users submits their name and the script creates a hash based on their input and creates a POST request with both the name and hash. The script then looks at the post request and checks if the hash that was submitted, matches the actual hash.

The problem that I currently have is generating the hash based on the users input because PHP is a *Pre*processor.

Would making an AJAX request fix this issue?

Edit: I am trying to make sure the user has not tamped with the data when it has been submitted.

Comment: Why are you trying to submit a hash based on the user input from the client side? Whats the purpose of this?

Comment: To verify that there was no tampering with the request. Otherwise, a user could find the curl request, and just change the name to be something else. Of course my application for this will not just have a users name,

Comment: Also, I am unsure of the best method to do this. I assumed submitting hash on client side, and verifying it server side would be the best method.

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is a CSRF token. Normally you would generate this on the server side and put it in the form, then verify it when the form is submitted. But it wouldn't have been made with user input.

Comment: CSRF would not be for me because I am not concerned that the user is coming from a different site. I want to protect the POST data being submitted. Someone could easily automate submitting data via command prompt + curl

Comment: Since the client code is known too, someone who could tamper with the post request could also regenerate the hash. A slightly safer approach would be to also hash in a value that was sent along with the form. That way, that someone also has to capture the previous event to know which "form token" to hash with the other data.

Comment: Well I was thinking if is done via PHP they could not find the hash function or salt. I am just trying to ensure the user visits the website when they submit the form and not make the request through curl/cmd prompt.
Do you have any examples of how I could implement that method in my code?

Comment: Anyone can make any HTTP request to your site at any time. That's just a matter of fact. To ensure that something hasn't been tampered with you first need to control both sides and only be worried about the transmission channel in the middle. But in your case, you have no control over either the transmission channel nor the sending side. The best you can do is offer some security for the transmission channel using SSL; that still leaves you with zero control of the sender and hence nothing really to prevent tampering of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to make sure the user has not tamped with the data when it has been submitted.

To be very blunt: this is a very stupid reason. The user is entering data into a form and submitting it to you. They are already "tampering" with the data. It doesn't make any sense to want to sign this data in any way. Even if the "problem" of PHP being a "pre-processor" would not exist, how would this work? PHP would take the data input by the user, sign it, then submit it to itself and check the signature? You can skip this whole process and just take the input of the user, that'll have the same outcome.

You could do the signing in Javascript, but this is equally nonsense. You're providing the Javascript code which can produce a valid signature to the client... what's stopping anyone from "tampering" with the data and then producing a valid signature for it?

Something that *would* make sense:

- You provide data to the user in a `hidden` form element and you want to check that the user did not alter this value while it was going server→client→server; in this case you can sign it with a hash and a *secret* which only the server knows and verify it this way. The key here is that there's a secret component on the server that the client doesn't have and can't fake.
- In the above scenario, you can also simply use sessions. In this case you're storing the data tamper-proof on the server itself where the client has no access at all. The advantage of the above signing approach is that it keeps the server stateless, while with sessions the server has to store state. They're both working towards the same end though.
- You want to prevent **third parties** from tampering with the data while it's transmitted from the client to you. The only realistic way to solve this is to use a SSL/TLS secured connection. This allows reasonably secured communication between the client and the server safe from tampering by third parties. The client will still be able to send any data to you at any time which you'll have to verify for correctness; signing or such is, again, not relevant here.

Comment: I have seen my method used on various different sites.. it submits the request with data `name=USERS_NAME&email=EMAIL&signature=XXXXXX`. If I copy this entire curl request and modify the name or email, the request won't be accepted because the signature is invalid. If the user goes to the website, and submits a valid submission, that is fine. But I have found people can write a simple perl for loop to iterate a list of names/emails and just fire off a curl request for the different variations. I am trying to prevent them from doing this.

Comment: Either what you were looking at was a **one time** CSRF token, *or* that signature was created via Javascript. But again, if you embed the necessary Javascript to create a signature in your site, I could very well go and write a Perl script which fires off random requests *with a valid signature*, because I have the Javascript code to create one. At best this only minimally deters very amateur script kiddies.